# Which neural network architectures solve my classification problem?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am new to deep learning so I need some advice. I have variables changing according to x, y coordinates, and year. For example, variable "a" changes according to "x, y coordinates" and variable "b" changes according to "year", and also, variable "c" changes according to both of them (x, y coordinates and year). I want to create a spatiotemporal prediction model. However, variable "c" affects the target variable "t" not only for that year but also according to its value in the previous 2 years. In that case, how can I create a spatiotemporal prediction model? Which neural network architectures solve my classification problem?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x': [40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1, 40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1, 40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1, 40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1, 40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1 ], 'y': [100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1, 100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1, 100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1, 100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1, 100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1], 'a': [1.0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 'b': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 ], 'c': [1.0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 't': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
        
         x        y      a    b      c   t  year
    0   40.1    100.1   1.0  1.0    1.0  1  2000
    1   50.1    110.1   0.0  1.0    1.0  1  2000
    2   60.1    120.1   1.0  1.0    1.0  1  2000
    3   70.1    130.1   1.0  1.0    0.0  0  2000
    4   80.1    140.1   0.0  1.0    0.0  0  2000
    5   90.1    150.1   0.0  1.0    0.0  0  2000
    6   0.0     160.1   0.0  1.0    0.0  0  2000
    7   300.1   400.1   0.0  1.0    0.0  0  2000
    8   40.1    100.1   1.0  0.5    1.0  0  2001
    9   50.1    110.1   0.0  0.5    0.0  1  2001
    10  60.1    120.1   1.0  0.5    1.0  0  2001
    11  70.1    130.1   1.0  0.5    0.0  0  2001
    12  80.1    140.1   0.0  0.5    0.0  1  2001
    13  90.1    150.1   0.0  0.5    0.0  1  2001
    14  0.0     160.1   0.0  0.5    1.0  0  2001
    15  300.1   400.1   0.0  0.5    0.0  0  2001
    16  40.1    100.1   1.0  0.9    1.0  0  2002
    17  50.1    110.1   0.0  0.9    0.0  1  2002
    18  60.1    120.1   1.0  0.9    0.0  1  2002
    19  70.1    130.1   1.0  0.9    0.0  1  2002
    20  80.1    140.1   0.0  0.9    1.0  0  2002
    21  90.1    150.1   0.0  0.9    1.0  0  2002
    22  0.0     160.1   0.0  0.9    0.0  1  2002
    23  300.1   400.1   0.0  0.9    0.0  0  2002
    24  40.1    100.1   1.0  0.3    1.0  0  2003
    25  50.1    110.1   0.0  0.3    0.0  1  2003
    26  60.1    120.1   1.0  0.3    0.0  1  2003
    27  70.1    130.1   1.0  0.3    0.0  1  2003
    28  80.1    140.1   0.0  0.3    0.0  0  2003
    29  90.1    150.1   0.0  0.3    0.0  1  2003
    30  0.0     160.1   0.0  0.3    1.0  0  2003
    31  300.1   400.1   0.0  0.3    1.0  0  2003
    32  40.1    100.1   1.0  0.2    1.0  0  2004
    33  50.1    110.1   0.0  0.2    0.0  0  2004
    34  60.1    120.1   1.0  0.2    0.0  0  2004
    35  70.1    130.1   1.0  0.2    0.0  1  2004
    36  80.1    140.1   0.0  0.2    1.0  1  2004
    37  90.1    150.1   0.0  0.2    0.0  0  2004
    38  0.0     160.1   0.0  0.2    0.0  0  2004
    39  300.1   400.1   0.0  0.2    0.0  0  2004
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not a matter of what model you use, but how you transform your features. You say that your target depends on past feature values, so you can rearrange your data to reflect this.

Here it is how to concatenate three consecutive rows into a single one.

```
X = df.drop("t", axis=1)
y = df["t"]

X = (
    pd.concat([X, X.shift(1), X.shift(2)], axis=1, keys=["t0", "t-1", "t-2"])
    .dropna()
)
y = y.iloc[2:]
```

```
>>> X.head()
    t0  t0  t0  t0  t0  t0      t-1 t-1 t-1 t-1 t-1 t-1     t-2 t-2 t-2 t-2 t-2 t-2
    x   y   a   b   c    year   x   y   a   b   c   year    x   y   a   b   c   year
2   60.1    120.1   1.0 1.0 1.0 2000    50.1    110.1   0.0 1.0 1.0 2000.0  40.1    100.1   1.0 1.0 1.0 2000.0
3   70.1    130.1   1.0 1.0 0.0 2000    60.1    120.1   1.0 1.0 1.0 2000.0  50.1    110.1   0.0 1.0 1.0 2000.0
4   80.1    140.1   0.0 1.0 0.0 2000    70.1    130.1   1.0 1.0 0.0 2000.0  60.1    120.1   1.0 1.0 1.0 2000.0
5   90.1    150.1   0.0 1.0 0.0 2000    80.1    140.1   0.0 1.0 0.0 2000.0  70.1    130.1   1.0 1.0 0.0 2000.0
```

You can now fit any classification model. I have chosen a simple logistic regressor from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

```
>>> clf.score(X, y)
0.7368421052631579
```

The same model on the plain data scores `0.625`, adding an extra timestep scores `0.8108`.

I'm not saying this is the only approach but certainly something to consider.

For more details you can read https://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/.